# How can I find out my Java version?

Tags: java

I am downloading and installing grails, and I need to set up some java system variables. How can I find out what my Java version is?

Answer (score 6):

in command prompt type: java -version

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the version of java you are running? Then yes, java -version.

Do you mean the latest java that Sun has to offer? java.sun.com?

I'm not sure I get your question.

Comment: honestly i dont know what i mean im sorry

Comment: Going by your user name, every_answer_gets_a_point, shouldn't you give Jeff an upvote ?

Comment: yes i gave him an upvote, but two others gave him downs

Comment: I'm pretty sure Downs is hereditary.

As for Java, the newest available version is Java 6u18.